# Taylor series expansion of $e^{-\lambda\tau}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Taylor series expansion of $e^{-\lambda\tau}$ yields:

$e^{-\lambda\tau}=1-\lambda\tau+o(\tau)$

and Taylor expansion of $\lambda\tau
e^{-\lambda\tau}$ equals:

$\lambda\tau
e^{-\lambda\tau}=\lambda\tau-\lambda^2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)=\lambda\tau+o(\tau)$.

Could anyone tell me why? How do we know that $o(\tau)$ satisfy

$\mathbb{lim}_{\tau\to 0}\frac{o(\tau)}{\tau}=0$?

Comment: What exactly is $P(m,x)$?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: $P(k,\tau) = e^{-\lambda\tau}\frac{(\lambda\tau)^k}{k!}$, this is Poisson PMF (probability of $k$ arrivals in interval $\tau$, but I think it doesn't matter much in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes, and that's the definition of the Landau symbols.

The exponential series is 
$$
\exp(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+…+\frac{x^n}{n!}+…
$$

The error term of
$$
\exp(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+…+\frac{x^n}{n!}+r_{n+1}(x)
$$
has one/the estimate
$$
|r_{n+1}(x)|\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}·\frac1{1-\frac{|x|}{n+2}}
$$
so that $r_{n+1}(x)=O(|x|^{n+1})$.

---

$f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is bounded for $x\to 0$, $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means that this fraction converges to zero.

This notation is misguiding, since $O(g(x))$ resp. $o(g(x))$ denotes the whole family of functions satisfying these limit conditions, and thus set notation should be used. For historical and practical reasons this is not done. So $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means $f\in O(g)$.

Comment: I'm not really sure why $\lambda\tau-\lambda^2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)=\lambda\tau+o(\tau)$... Why $-\lambda^2\tau^2+O(\tau^3) = o(\tau)$?

Comment: Because $O(x^2)\subset o(x)$.  Thus $−λ^2τ^2+O(τ^3)=O(τ^2)=o(τ)$. Better, but unusual notation would be $−λ^2τ^2+O(τ^3)\subseteq O(τ^2)\subset o(τ)$. I do not know why your source insists on the small $o$, since the big $O$ statement is equally true and stronger.

Comment: Stronger meaning it conveys more information than small $o$? You said big $O$ means the fraction is bounded (what you mean is probably bounded function, right?) I thought that convergence to zero tells us more than the fact a function is bounded...

Comment: Yes to all, and to the last, you are comparing $O(τ^2)$ to $o(τ)$, $O(τ^2)⊂o(τ)⊂O(τ)$.

Comment: I'm wondering why wikipedia uses a different definition of small-o notation (the fraction tends to zero as $x\to\infty$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: That depends on the limit. Here we are concerned with $x\approx 0$. In complexity theory, for example, one is interested in the asymptotic behavior for very large input sizes.

Comment: Then in our case, also $|f(n)|\leq\epsilon|g(n)|\qquad$ for all $n\geq N$ isn't a correct definition? I think they should mention it somewhere.

Comment: It is mentioned. In the introduction the case $x\to a$ and under **Infinitesimal asymptotics** the case $x\to 0$.

Comment: $O(\tau^2) \subset o(\tau)$ means that if something is $O(\tau^2)$, it is also $o(\tau)$, but not vice versa? Is it a general rule we can prove? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Take rational powers. $τ^{3/2}=o(τ)$ but not in $O(τ^2)$

Comment: Ok, but how about the other direction - showing that if $O(\tau^2)$, then $o(\tau)$?

Comment: If $|f(x)|<cx^2$ then of course also $|f(x)|/|x|<c|x|$ is arbitrarily small when $x\to 0$.

Comment: This is true because dividing both sides of inequality by a positve number doesn't change that inequality? Or maybe there's some other reason?